# Using Managed Extensibility Framework and Bot Framework

Tags: c#, mef, botframework

I'm creating a c# bot framework application that leverages Microsoft's LUIS. I would like to use the Managed Extensibility Framework to manage many LUIS intents the bot framework application would be utilizing. Is using MEF a fitting solution to this problem/ would use MEF in this situation work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd probably be overkill. I don't see a major extensibility situation here: if your bot uses natural language recognition with LUIS, your code will always depend on the intents you define, as you need to state the behaviour associated to each intent.

However, I could think of having a container that picks 'small components that provide LUIS handlers' up, and then by using Reflection it injects them on certain Dialogs you specified. Each Dialog should depend on a interface for managing LUIS intents, but their logic would be really generic and would break the idea of having dialogs.

Maybe you can explain a little but more of what are your requirements and what made you thinking about using MEF for that scenario.

Comment: Yeah I don't think it fits the situation. The LUIS intents always need to be available for matching, and the app still is maintainable without MEF. Thanks for the insight